# How to get Intent first and then only create a fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, android-intent, android-asynctask, oncreate, android-intentservice

In one of my activities onCreate method I'm passing in an ArrayList from an intent into the fragment to create the fragment. However, I realised it would throw null pointer exception as the fragment might be created before receiving the intent?How should I fix this?In my onCreate method.

```
monitor_list= this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("monitorList");

    cholesterol_monitor = (ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor>) monitor_list;





    monitorListFragment = MonitorListFragment.newInstance(cholesterol_monitor);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_monitor_layout, monitorListFragment)
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

check first if the monitor_list is not null then if it's not replace the fragment

```
    ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor> monitor_list= this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("monitorList");
    if (monitor_list.size()>0){
        cholesterol_monitor = (ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor>) monitor_list;
        monitorListFragment = MonitorListFragment.newInstance(cholesterol_monitor);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_monitor_layout, monitorListFragment)
                .commit();
    }else // list is null
```

Comment: I found out that the monitor_list is not null but some locations in it is null so I need to add a check and put a default value for null locations but I'm not sure how to do that?